# window.location.state.buttonEnabled always fails check for undefined with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to read the value of `window.location.state.endButtonEnabled` to check for undefined. But when I actually go ahead and check for undefined I get an undefined error at the if condition. In the following code:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        if(window.location.state.endButtonEnabled !== undefined){
            console.log('endButtonEnabled is: '+ window.location.state.endButtonEnabled );
            //Do Something
        }
        else{
            window.location.state = {endButtonEnabled: true};
        }
    }
```

Consider the error in the console:
[image: JS Error]

I tried similar variations of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39837954/3096097) to no avail. Any suggestions? I'm using the latest version of ReactJS.

Comment: The error message is not saying that `endButtonEnabled` is undefined, it is saying that `state` is undefined. You should first check the `state` and then the `endButtonEnabled` ... `window.location.state === undefined && window.location.state.endButtonEnabled === undefined`

Comment: I was able to get a solution. I'll post an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "state" property in the window.location object. So window.location.state is undefined the first time you run the check, breaking your code. It doesn't even get to the `endButtonEnabled` property.

Why are you putting state into window.location anyways? I assume you are trying to manage the state of your component? You shouldn't be doing that inside of window.location, the entire window object is made by the browser and not something you should be altering without good reason. Look at these [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) to better understand how to manage state.

Comment: Do you have an alternative way to do this? Maybe you can edit your answer to include that.

Comment: I linked you the relevant docs on how to manage state. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class) are docs on how to add state to your component period if that is what you need. In any case, you should not be storing state inside of window.location.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to first check for `window.location.state === undefined`. This lead to the following solution while using `navigate('/path/destination')`. Surprisingly `navigate()` from `'@reach/router'` preserves `window.location.state` so I was able to use that when coming back from the next page. So the final code I ended up with for the check is:

```
if(window.location.state === undefined){
    window.location.state = {endButtonEnabled: false}
}
else{
    window.location.state = {endButtonEnabled: true}
}
```

This code does not break when loading the page for the first time. This may not be the ideal way to state manage things, but this way works for me. I guess the takeaway is: do as the docs say, not as I do.